# Where do I find the length of the seasons in Rokugan?

Tags: l5r-4e, weather, rokugan, calendar

Rokugan has a rather large canon lore, and I am a little dumbstruck when trying to sift through all of them for the information I seek about the climate of Rokugan.

In particular, I try to find out when the seasons are changing, and if Rokugan does feature a "rainy season" like Japan, which is kind of an addition to in between Spring and Summer there. For example, the year 2019/20 has the following dates for its seasons in Kyoto Area:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 34 in the core rulebook is where you will want to go for the rundown of Rokugan's calendar. It will give you the broad strokes of the seasons. As far as I can recall this is the most complete information there is on the topic from this edition.

If you don't find what you are looking for there you can find more specific tidbits scattered throughout the books, usually salted in among descriptions of specific locations, for example: Emerald Empires p.24 has this to say about coastal Crane lands:

> "Rainfall is abundant, since seasonal winds carry a great deal of moisture to this part of the Emerald Empire, and the flora along the Crane coast is rich and verdant. The spring rainy season lasts about a month, and the summer that follows is hot and humid."

Searching for those slivers of insight is probably not worth your time though, my last suggestion would be to try the L5R wiki's page on [Time](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Time).

Comment: 4th edition core, right? Those tiny tidbits is what I search for, yes!

Comment: I think the Core book and Emerald Empire are your best bet to find weather/climate related minutiae but I wouldn't be surprised to find them in any book that brings up new locations.
Atlas of Rokugan might have something but I haven't got my hands on that one.
The Books of [Elements] all have a section detailing specific regions, 
the Book of Air has a section called *Air as the Agent of Weather* on page 107 that looks promising.
The Great Clans and Strongholds of the Empire have sections on various locations.
Secrets of the empire details the lands of Minor Clans